# Editing google calendar through web application

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have an application that needs to automatically add events to a google calendar. The problem is that all users of the application do not have access to the google calendar, so they cannot be asked to grant access to the application.

Is there a way to grant API access to a google calendar without asking it from the current user? Or maybe to authenticate once and store that authentication?

I am sure it is covered somewhere in the Google documentation, but I can't seem to find an answer to the situation I am looking at.

Thanks!
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authorization information can be stored on the file system, so subsequent executions will not prompt for authorization. Check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app) to know how to perform authorization in a web application. Here is an [example](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php#step_3_set_up_the_sample) on how to store the credentials to system.

```
// Store the credentials to disk.    
    if(!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
          mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, $accessToken);
        printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
      }
      $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
```